# Array with select option in Angular and Typescript

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I display 51 questions with their related answers on a page. 
Both information come from one web-service call.

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let QuestionOption of questions; trackBy: trackQuestionById; let i = index;">
   <th scope="row">{{QuestionOption.id}}</th>
   <td>{{QuestionOption.name}} {{QuestionOption.description}}
    </p>
     <select  class="form-control"  name="selectAnswer" [(ngModel)]="answer[i]">
     <option *ngFor="let answers of QuestionOption.Answers" [ngValue]="answers.id">{{answers.description}}</option>
    </p>
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

on the typescript code I try the following:

```
answer: Answer[];
this.answer = new Array<Answer>();
```

The type Answer has multiple fields like: Id, Name, Score, Description

What is not working is that I always have get the Id into the answer[i]
but I want to have the id in the field answer[i].id

If i change the

```
[(ngModel)]="answer[i]"
```

into

```
[(ngModel)]="answer[i].id"
```

I get the following exception:
ERROR TypeError: "_co.caaAnswer[_v.context.index] is undefined"

I also tried:

```
[(ngModel)]="answer[i]?.id"
```

So is it correct to use answer[i] ? and then in the option I should somehow assign to answer[i].id the selected value. If so somebody can help how to do it.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot.
augeres

Comment: As an additional information it is important to say that the display works fine. It is just the saving of the information which does not work.

Comment: why u made answer as array?

Comment: @ArunKumarMN as I have 51 questions and next to it I have the related answers. Each question has a potential individual set of answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that the compareWith function did not work properly because of the Array. It only works in case you name the html select based upon the array index:

Working version:

```
<select class="form-control" id="field_answer{{i}}" name="field_answer{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="resultAnswer[i].answer" [compareWith]="compareFn">
<option [ngValue]="answer" *ngFor="let answer of Question.answers; trackBy: trackAnswerById">{{answer.id}} {{answer.description}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to push into answer on select change like this

```
<select  class="form-control"  name="selectAnswer" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswerId" (change)="setAnswer(i)">
 <option *ngFor="let answers of QuestionOption.Answers" [ngValue]="answers.id">{{answers.description}}</option>
<select>
```

in component.ts

```
selectedAnswerId : number;
setAnswer(index){
  this.answer[index].push({id : this.selectedAnswerId})
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this:
this.caaAnswers[index] = { id : this.selectedAnswerId[index] };

and in the component: 
[(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer[i]

As I have a set of questions and potential answers.
But your code works fine!!! Thank you